# Eclipse gets stuck on startup with an old stashed commit

Tags: eclipse

So I had my repo open in Eclipse with the stashed commit view. After discarding the stash in the command line, I reopened Eclipse. Eclipse is still trying to open in the stashed commit view which was discarded. This is crashing the program. I tried removing the .lock and .log files but without any success. The Stashed commit view cannot be closed either due to the program being stuck at startup.

Answer (score 0):

Cleared issue by running eclipse with -clearPersistedState from terminal/command prompt